# How to obtain public ip address using windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, shell, ip, ip-address, command-prompt

Any way of doing this through the command prompt without using any third party software or relying on powershell?

A simple command would be great like on Linux/Mac which I use `curl http://ipinfo.io/ip` for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the **Invoke-WebRequest** module in powershell. For example:

```
Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip
```

[Go to source](https://jfrmilner.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/powershell-quick-tip-03-whats-my-external-ip-address-windows-command-line/)

Edit: I misread the question and thought you needed to use Powershell, there is no built in command in `cmd.exe` to return a public IP address, but you can use `nslookup` to resolve it, like so;

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com
```

Another option for the OP:

```
telnet curlmyip.com 80
```

Type `GET` after you are connected.

**Note**: telnet is not installed/enabled by default on Windows.

[Go to source](https://superuser.com/questions/165986/windows-command-that-returns-external-ip)

Comment: Any way of doing it on the command prompt and not using powershell?

Comment: Keep getting _DNS request timed out_ when using that command. :/

Comment: This is a basic nslookup command. As long as you can resolve to external DNS addresses, this will work. It's possible you do not have your dns resolvers configured properly. You could try using Google's DNS resolvers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) but you will need to look at that on your local machine.

Comment: There is no command that obtains the public IP address in command prompt. This is simply a workaround to the limitation you imposed. A clever "trick" if you will. You're better off using power shell which does actually have a function for doing what you want.

You could try using telnet if it is installed. It's not installed/enabled on Windows by default.

Comment: The real beef here I guess is that OpenDNS apparently offers this service by allowing you to query their server for the label `myip.opendns.com`. Probably the answer should spell this out; as it stands, it looks like "here's how to use `nslookup`".

Answer (score 14):

Simplest way & Cross platform solution (Mac, Windows, and Linux)

> `curl "http://myexternalip.com/raw"`

& You Will get public IPV4.

Comment: **curl** is also installed, if you install `git bash` -> `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw32\bin\curl.exe` or `xampp` -> `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl.exe`

Answer (score 8):

you can use these commands in both Windows and Linux

> `curl ifconfig.me`

Curl is something that is built-in Windows when you upgrade to the latest version, so it's not called a third-party software.

or

> `curl ifconfig.co`

In Linux, almost Distros have this command already.

Thanks so much **ArthurG** for your commands. It works perfectly and can be used for Batch script in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl ip-adresim.app
```

It supports both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for normal dos batch

```
@echo off
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | find "Address" >"%temp%\test1.txt"
more +1 "%temp%\test1.txt" >"%temp%\test2.txt"
set /p MyIP=<%temp%\test2.txt
del %temp%\test2.txt
set MyIP=%MyIP:~10%
echo %MyIP%
```

Now, %MyIP% will can be echo or used as a variable for additional batch use.

Answer (score 2):

This command works for me:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com
```

Comment: nslookup works but sometimes it yields ipv6 instead of 4, which can cause a headache...

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner, no curl or powershell, just bare CMD, raw ip for IP4

```
FOR /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=:\ " %G IN ('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com 2^>^&1 ^|find "dress"') DO @echo %G
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could use the very same command, both in Linux and Windows:

```
 curl http://ipinfo.io/ip
```

I use it as part of a batch file like so:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`curl http://ipinfo.io/ip`) DO (
SET currentip=%%F
)
ECHO %currentip%
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows/Linux version:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

Unix version:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Comment: There is nothing particularly "Unix" about `dig`; there is also `host`. All three of `nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` are commonly installed on Unix / Linux / Mac, though typically at most one of them will be part of the standard install on any given platform (though on my Mac, I have all three in `/usr/bin`; but maybe that's part of XCode). `nslookup` used to be part of the base Windows install but I'm guessing this may no longer be true, either.

Comment: Anyway, this basically duplicates the information from the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
curl http://ip.jsontest.com/ > ip.json
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('type ip.json') do (set publicip=%%a)
set publicip=%publicip:{=%
set publicip=%publicip:}=%
set publicip=%publicip:"=%
echo %publicip:~1%
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is call this url in **CURL** in cmd or other command lines

```
curl ip.dnslab.link
```

response will be like this **json**

```
84.241.47.110
```